# Does Coffeescript support nested list comprehensions?

Tags: coffeescript

For example, given the following structure

```
    pages = [
        [
            { myvar: 1},
            { myvar: 2},
            { myvar: 3},
        ]
    ];
```

How can I express the folling (python-like) comprehension?

```
v.myvar for p in pages for v in p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you can not, see: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/1191

A workaround in the meantime (until CoffeeScript gets improved):

```
pages = [
        [
            { myvar: 1},
            { myvar: 2},
            { myvar: 3},
        ]
    ];

result = []
for row in pages
  for map in row
    result.push map.myvar

console.log result
```

which outputs:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: thanks :) this is what i already have in my code and i wanted to refactor it as nested comprehension.

Comment: You can actually make it *slightly* more succinct: `result.push map.myvar for map in row for row in pages`.